# Android: How to make a Surface View and button on the same screen?

Tags: android, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

what I have so far is two classes,which the first one is a plain "welcome page" with a enter button to the main page and when user clicks then the 2nd class show up with a surface view and a button to capture a picture.what I have done so far is I followed the steps in "marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html"; and it all works fine to show the surface view and capture a picture but now the problem is I want to use OCR to extract the text from the captured picture. I'm thinking about using "TESSERACT" and follow the steps in "http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html"; ?? Any recommendation is welcome? thanks + I'm new to android and programming.

Comment: This kind of rambling comment isn't going to get you anywhere: *"I tried many links and resources to understand How can I do that but get errors such as black screen or just button or emulator stop working and gives me error when it goes to the page."*  Reading this I have no clue what you've done or what the result was. You need to try **one** thing at a time, explain what you've done, put up the source code, and then clearly describe the problem if you want to get helped.

Comment: thanks.basically I have two classes,which the first one is a plain "welcome page" with a enter to the main page and when user click that then the 2nd class show up with a surface view and a button to capture a picture.what I have done so far is I followed the steps in "http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html" and it all works fine but now the problem is I want to use OCR to extract the text from the captured picture.Im thinking about using "TESSERACT" and follow the steps in "http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html" ?any recommendation?ta

Answer (score 0):

try to use the overlay with ImageButton.
Create new Android XML layout file, for example overlay.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageButton 
      android:id="@+id/bTake"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_snap" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

To create overlay in main code use the LayoutInflater.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View overlay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(overlay, params);
    shotBtn = (ImageButton) overlay.findViewById(R.id.bTake);
```